# Shouldn't a refrigerator be on its own circuit?

Tags: wiring, kitchens, circuit-breaker

I thought major appliances like refrigerators in newer houses were supposed to be on dedicated circuits.

I just replaced a melted outlet in my kitchen. It was a 15 amp outlet, wired as a pass-through using the screw terminals. The outlet says "For 15A branch circuits only". (The breaker on this circuit is 20A)

The same circuit powers the fridge, 2 outlets in the kitchen (one of which powers a toaster), a couple of outlets in the laundry room, and outlet on the floor in the kitchen. I haven't traced the wiring for certain but I'm pretty sure the fridge and toaster outlets pass through the outlet that melted.

I replaced the outlet and re-wired it using pig-tails rather than pass-through, but if the outlet says "For 15A branch circuits only" that sure sounds to me like it's not rated to be anywhere on a 20A circuit.

So my questions are 2:

Should a house built in 2000 in Fairfax county, Virginia have a large refrigerator on a shared circuit? (It was built to order by a supposedly well-regarded builder.)

Is there any way it's ok to have an outlet that says "For 15A branch circuits only" wired into a 20A circuit? Somebody on another thread here said something like "All 15A outlets are rated for 20A pass-through" but an outlet that is explicitly labeled as only for 15A circuits sure seems like it doesn't belong on a 20A circuit.

Comment: What make/part number is the damaged receptacle, or is it some unlabeled piece of builder-grade (or worse) junk?

Comment: It's a Leviton outlet. It does have a UL stamp. Hard to tell the model or part number. I see what looks like `NOM 057` stamped onto it. It also has what looks like `0121G2`, but it's faint and hard to read.

Comment: It isn't possible to use a push in connection made for 14ga with 12ga wire; it won't fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US a residential kitchen fridge is not required to be on a dedicated circuit. This is a tradeoff.  If it's shared with a lighting circuit or even outlets, you may be more quick to notice if there's ever a problem.  A fridge with a dedicated outlet is NOT required to have GFCI protection, and some fridge manufacturers recommend against GFCI for the fridge outlet.

Answer (score 9):

In the US, under the NEC, a residential kitchen fridge is not *required* to be on a dedicated circuit. It is certainly a good idea and best practice, but not a requirement. A fridge can be on one of the minimum two required "small appliance branch circuits".

A 15A duplex receptacle is rated for 20A feed-thru. What you are reading about "15A only" is regarding the push-in wire connections in the back of the receptacle. They are limited to #14 solid wire and a 15A circuit. Check out the wording in the image in this related answer: [Can a 20 amp circuit have a 14 gauge pigtail directly to one receptacle?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38576/can-a-20-amp-circuit-have-a-14-gauge-pigtail-directly-to-one-receptacle/70008?noredirect=1#comment147559_70008)

A "well-regarded" builder would never put a fridge on with the counter receptacles. Not unless this is a code-minimum tract home.

As for kitchen receptacles being shared with receptacles in a laundry area, this has not been allowed by code for many years. Well before 2000.

Comment: I haven't seen a fridge whose peak draw is more than a couple hundred watts (2 amps or so).  Why would you want it on a dedicated line?

Comment: The wording on the back of the receptacle is pretty vague. It isn't at all clear if the "For 15A branch circuit only" regards the push-in connection or the entire receptacle. The block of text that contains that phrase does start out with "Push in #14    CU Solid wire" and then the 15A restriction is on the next line.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, its a convenience thing. You don't want to have to worry about tripping a breaker if a high draw appliance is being used. Besides, most full size fridges are 5-7a, with high-end models sometimes will over 10a.

Comment: @DuncanC, IMO it is quite clear. It starts right off with "push-in connections....."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the AC motor in the fridge can spike well over its "normal" amperage when starting. If you were out of the house for a day or two, would you want to come home to a tripped breaker and melted ice cream? Best to put a fridge on a dedicated 20A circuit to minimize the risk.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft last week while chasing a power problem, I measured the power my old fridge drew.  It was 7A for about a second at startup, then settled down into the 1A range.

Comment: I just revisited this thread after a long time. Thanks for the explanation on 20A feed-through. I gather it's a code violation to use the push-in wire connections for the feed-through? That is, I think, what the electrician did here, and probably what caused the problem. The push-in connectors were getting over-loaded with more than 15A of feed-through current. This is the second outlet in my house that has melted. One, in my office, got so hot that it left scorch-marks on the paint on the baseboard into which it was installed.

Comment: Builders are lazy, and use those push-in wire connectors for everything, ESPECIALLY feed-throughs. It enables them to skip pigtails and wiring nuts. For a 15A outlet on a 20A circuit it seems like a very bad idea however.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey this is a high end "Estate home". The electrical work was pretty shoddy, I'm afraid. e.g.: One GFI outlet used to feed multiple bathroom outlets, shower light and fan, most outlets in the garage, porch outlet, and monument lights. (in heavy rain the buried wires  to the monument light leaked a little current to ground, tripping the GFI and killing the power to all that, including our sprinkler system, FIOS phone and network, landscape lighting, bathroom outlets, etc. (I'm not positive that it fed bathroom receptacles. It's been many years.)

Comment: I fixed that problem by diagramming all the places that were served by the single GFI and adding 3 or 4 additional GFI outlets so each one served a small section of the total circuit, and the monument lights had their own dedicated GFI. Now when there is really heavy rain ONLY the monument lights go out. It was a big job figuring it all out in a finished house, and took me a couple of weekends to complete. And the builder probably saved <50 bucks total by only using 1 GFI for all that. Maddening.